# add JsonP-Format for callback function to restler

Tags: php, jsonp, restler

I´m trying to add JSONP Format to lucarest restler api without luck

As mentioned in this thread
[jsonpsupport](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/17)

i added a new file jsonpformat.php with the given context into my vendor/ folder where
restler.php resides.
Then i added the

```
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonpFormat','JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat');
```

to my index.php but restlerExlorer does´t fire up anymore and the server logs says

> ...RestException' with message 'Class 'JsonpFormat' not found'...

But i put it into the folders that were stared in the thread...
Help would be great.
Thx
Inge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We took the suggestion in the same thread and named our JSONP format as `JsFormat`

So just use

```
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsFormat','JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat');
```